# How can I set a background image for the QTabWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How can I set a background image for the QTabWidget in Qt?

I've already tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/img.jpg);");
```

And can I set a background image for the specific tab of the QTabWIdget?

Comment: 1. Give it a full path and try again, possibly something wrong in relative path 
2. Yes you can

Comment: @Tay2510 it is a full path.

Comment: @FrozenHeart, try to set custom border with custom background.

Comment: This should work if the image was added to the resources.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code to set the style of `QTabWidget` `Tab` and set `Image` on to it:

```
QString category = "QTabBar::tab:first { height: 30px; width: 100px;border-image: url(/home/vx/Downloads/Images/category.png); }";
QString counter= "QTabBar::tab:middle { height: 30px; width: 100px;border-image: url(/home/vx/Downloads/Images/counter.png); }";
QString user="QTabBar::tab:last { height: 30px; width: 100px;border-image: url(/home/vx/Downloads/Images/user.png); }";

ui->TB_main->tabBar()->setStyleSheet(category+counter+user);
```